# /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata Error

Tags: android, root, android-rom, custom-rom, redmi-device

I have tried to install `RR-N-v5.8.0-20170106-dior-Official.zip` with `PhilZ Touch 6`.

After Wipe `Dalvik/ART` Cache and tried to install zip I got the below error.
could not detect file system for `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata`
Can any one help me on this.

Device I am using : Red-mi Note 4G LTE Single SIM
Its rooted.